# Is there a way to add padding to text in an element only when text is present?

Tags: html, css

Using only HTML5 and CSS3 is there a way to add padding or at least what appears to be padding to text in an element only when text is present?

Here's some example code and a demo to work with.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    background-color:red;
}

.text {
    text-align:center;  
    font-size:18px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <p class='text'>text</p>
</div>
```

The structure can change as long as when there is no text, container is `0px` high.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D9Lxc/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.text {
    text-align: center;  
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.text:empty {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Note that this will not work in IE<8. If you need it to, you could either use JavaScript (such as `if (text.children.length === 0) text.style.padding = '0px'`) or a JavaScript fallback library like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Here is [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9Lxc/2/).

Here is [an MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) for the `:empty` psuedo-class.